# Google maps Geocoder языковые настройки

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как выставить правильные языковые настройки в данной конструкции

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = 'г.Прилуки ул.Михайловская 12';
geocoder.geocode({'address': address},function(results, status){
        var addr = {};
        addr.city = results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
        addr.region = results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
        addr.location = results[0].geometry.location;
        addr.formatted_address = results[0].formatted_address;
        console.log(addr);
    });
```

Мне приходит : к примеру

```
Object {city: "Прилуки", region: "Чернігівська область", location: vf, formatted_address: "Михайлівська вулиця, Прилуки, Чернігівська область, Украина"}
```

Я же хочу чтобы приходило тоже самое но на на русском языке.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': address, 'language':'ru'},function(results, status){
```

Comment: не работает, пробывал)) а как еще можно этот параметр не додумался...

Comment: @IgorKalamurda, тогда в месте подключения скрипта в его адрес допишите `&language=ru`.

Comment: написано 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=ru'

Comment: чуть понял в чем прикол, только не понял как его решить если просто по ссылке забить без улици, то выдает русский, если дописать улицу то украинским пишет(

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8&language=ru&sensor=false

Comment: @IgorKalamurda, видимо улицы для города Прилуки существуют только на украинском языке. На карте в браузере аналогично.

Comment: Да видимо вы правы...

Comment: Вытягивал улици по Yandex maps api